# Flutter how i can use a setState event without refresh my futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, colors, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a question.

At the moment i try to build a category list with data from firebase.

To load the data i use a futurebuilder.

Here my category list:

[image]

Now i want to implement a color change event if i click on a list element.
For example, if i click on tree the element tree should change the color.

My problem:

I create a object for every category.
If i try to change the color i use in futurebuilder a setState.
The setState refresh my Object.
How i can use a setState without reload my the futurebuilder?

Many thx (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this little trick.
For example, this is your future:

```
Future<void> yourFuture async{
// do something
}
```

Use a `final` `temp` variable to store your `future` like this:

```
final temp = yourFuture;
```

Then use it in your `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder(
future: temp,
builder: (context, snapshot){}
),
```

Comment: Greate, many thx :D It's working. You saved my day

Comment: Hehehe, no problem !